# transparent back ground

Tags: html, pdf, itext, transparent

When using HTML to PDF, I'm getting odd results trying to align a bit of 
text in dead center of page without a colored background to the div.

Now, I can not seem to be able to get an h1 or p to pad from the top either  
but I can get a div to pad down, but not align center.

Any tips for me please.

:}

```
PdfReader template = new PdfReader(Server.MapPath("~/Cirtificate.pdf"));
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new     FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/test.pdf"), FileMode.Create));
document.Open();

PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(template, 1);
document.NewPage();
cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string htmlText = wc.DownloadString("http://localhost:65061/TEST_OUTPUT_PAGE.html");

StringReader sr = new StringReader(htmlText);
XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, sr);  
document.Close();

Response.Redirect("~/test.pdf");
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    position: static;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this page for a list of supported CSS styles](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm) on various objects. I would recommend wrapping your `<p>` in a `<div>` using padding on the `<div>` and alignment on the `<p>`.

```
var outputFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Test1.pdf");
using (var fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
    using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4)) {
        using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs)) {
            document.Open();
            var html = "<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><div style=\"padding-top:200px;\"><p style=\"text-align:center;padding-top:200px;\">This is a test</p></div></body></html>";
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(html)) {
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, sr);
            }
            document.Close();
        }
    }
}
```